# sqlite database size low level control

Tags: sqlite

I am developing a simple storage for points in an sqlite database, the problem is that space consumption on disk is slightly unsatisfying. Here is what I mean:

A program to generate some data for the database:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double lat = 180*(rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX);
    double lon = 180*(rand()*1.0/RAND_MAX);
    int64_t id = rand()*1LL*rand();
    cout << id << "," << lat << "," << lon << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To import the data run:

```
g++ filldb.cpp
echo 100000 | ./a.out > db.text
sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table points(id UNSIGNED INT, lat REAL, lon REAL);
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import db.text points
```

The size of the database right after this shows `3.3M`, however the "real" size of data is 100000*(8 bytes)*3 = `2.4M` and after

```
sqlite> create index points_index on points(id);
```

the database size more than doubles to `5.1M`

**Q** where does the space go (i don't mean the space for index but the overhead of storing data) and how can one control low level behaviour of storage/indexes and can one do it at all?

The points database is just an example, I would like to store something like `id -> payload` mapping where payload size is known in advance and is same for every id.

Comment: Run the [sqlite3_analyzer](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: @CL thanks, I didn't know about it. I guess the relevant part is `Size of the file in bytes......................... 5328896
Bytes of user payload stored...................... 2799305     52.5%` can one do anything about it?

Comment: Try making the `id` column INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: thanks, that does create an index automatically right? I also found this, http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html. Essentially it removes a hidden column from database

Comment: @CL from what I know sqlite uses 64bit ids on primary key column. Is there a way to tell it to use 32 bit? Or this has something to do with the size of pointer size on a machine?

Comment: It uses [up to 64 bits](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

Comment: quoting the page you mentioned: "Each entry in a table b-tree consists of a 64-bit signed integer key"

Comment: And that 64-bit integer is *stored* as a varint.

Comment: @CL sorry to bug, but could you elaborate? Can i somehow control the way it is stored to reduce the size of the db?

Comment: In SQLite, all integer values logically have 64 bits. However, values are stored with less than 64 bits, if possible.

Comment: @CL your suggestion for `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` worked, I have `3.2MB` together with index. Inspecting the database shows there is quite a bit of free space. Is it possible to tell sqlite that there won't be any more inserts and that it can optimise something?